# Refresh a DIV in Laravel every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, partial-page-refresh

I started learning Laravel a little while ago and almost finished my Laravel 5.4 project. There is just one thing I can't get working and that is refreshing only a particular DIV section in a overview blade page. I looked and tried with javascript examples but it doesn't work.
So hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a page which shows a list of available live streams. I want to change that status from offair to live if the status in my mySQL databse is changed (manually at first) I need to refresh that page every 5 seconds so viewers can see if a stream status is live or offair.

From examples I tried the following javascript (placed in the header section):

```
<script>

    (function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            axios.get('layouts.partials.refreshstreamoverview',)
                .then(function(response){
                        document.querySelector('#partial')
                                .innerHtml(response.data);
                }); // do nothing for error - leaving old content.
            }); 
        }, 3000); // milliseconds

</script>
```

My Route is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'streams'], function () {

        Route::get('', 'StreamsController@index');

    });
```

@index gives me all the streams available (whether offair or live)

My StreamsController looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\District;
use App\Gemeente;
use App\User;
use App\Stream;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StreamsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $streams = Stream::orderBy('district_id')
        ->orderBy('gemeente_id')
        ->get();

        return view('streams.index', compact('streams'));
    }

}
```

Nothing gets refreshed after 5 seconds unfortunatly. Does someone have any idea how I can solve this? Much appreciated !

Comment: Have you defined the route "'layouts.partials.refreshstreamoverview" ?

Comment: What do you mean? In the routes/web.php you mean?

Comment: You're passing 'layouts.partials.refreshstreamoverview"  value to axios.get method, so I think 'layouts.partials.refreshstreamoverview" is the route path. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. That is situated in the resources/views/partials folder as refreshstreamoverview.blade.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one route. You need the route to render the partial, like:

```
Route::get('partial', 'StreamsController@partial');
```

Then you need to create the `partial` method in the controller, and your JavaScript should fetch the URL defined in the routes file (`streams/partial`).

What you tried to use as route (`layouts.partials.refreshstreamoverview`) is actually the template. You need to pass it to the `view` method, in your `partial` action in the controller, similar to what you did in `view('streams.index', ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Tried to do that but still not working. Added a method to the StreamsController like:

        public function partial()
        {
            $streams = Stream::orderBy('district_id')
            ->orderBy('gemeente_id')
            ->get();

            return view('streams.index', compact('streams'));
        }

and added:

    Route::get('partial', 'StreamsController@partial');

to my routes.

Comment: Did you change the JS? You need to use `/partial` or `/streams/partial`(if you added the route inside the prefix) instead of `layouts.partials.refreshstreamoverview`.